# Cannot access Dotenv environment variable bundled with Webpack on client side (Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export)

Tags: javascript, github, webpack, dotenv

I've been learning code for 6 months, I've always managed to find answers by myself... until now. I've been stuck for a week, so, it might be time to ask for help! Actually, I've probably been struggling that much because I've focused my learning on the front-end, and it's the first time I need to touch to the backend.

To give you some context, I'm currently working on a personal project, a website for a beauty salon. On that web site, I'm using an API key to fetch two different Google APIs (maps and place) to display a map showing the location of the salon and its Google reviews.

I have a public repo on GitHub for that project, and I'd like to set it up on GitHub pages, so people can see the live version of it as I might display this project on my portfolio. The problem is, my API key obviously needs to stay hidden, but the website still needs to access the key to show the map and reviews.

I had no idea how to do that but after many researches, that's what I tried to implement:

1. I created myself an account on [dotenv](https://www.dotenv.org/) and followed step by stem their tutorial ["CI/CD in Node.js with GitHub Actions"](https://www.dotenv.org/docs/languages/nodejs/github-actions). Basically:

   - I installed and configured dotenv.
   - I created my .env file containing my API key.
   - I built my .env.vault.
   - I retrieved my DOTENV_KEY, and added it to GitHub as an "Action Secret" of my repo in order to unlock my vault with it during my workflow on GitHub Actions.
   - I created the workflow to unlock the vault and retrieve my API key.
2. My API key stored as process.env.KEY is now available in Node.js (server side) but unfortunately not in the browser (client side) so I installed [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to be able to access it. That's what I've done:

   - I followed the [get started with webpack guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started) to have a basic set up. Then I modified the webpack.config.js in a way that was supposed to let me use environment variables in the bundled file.
   - I assigned my API key (process.env.KEY) to a variable and exported it with the Node syntax. I bundled the file and then tried to retrieve the variable in two js file, those where I fetch the API, but it definitely doesn't work. I always get this error message in my browser console whenever I try to print out the value of the variable:

---

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default**

OR

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: myVarName**

---

I've seen online that this type of error usually happens when there is an incompatibility of ES and CommonJS modules, so I tried to make sure that I was using the same syntax everywhere. I also tried named and default exports/ imports. Nothing changed.

Then, I found a plugin called [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) which is supposed to kinda improve the support of environment variables in webpack. I installed it and configured it. The problem is still the same.

Here is a simplified example of the important files of my project, with a fake API key:

.github/workflows/ci.yml

```
name: npm run build
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build
      env:
        DOTENV_KEY: ${{ secrets.DOTENV_KEY }}
```

dist/bundle.js

```
(()=>{var r={858:r=>{const o="0123456789";r.exports=o,console.log(o)}},o={};!function t(e){var s=o[e];if(void 0!==s)return s.exports;var n=o[e]={exports:{}};return r[e](n,n.exports,t),n.exports}(858)})();
```

js/browsersidemaps.js AND js/browsersidereviews.js

```
import { KEY } from '../dist/bundle.js';
console.log(KEY);
```

src/nodeside.js

```
const KEY = process.env.KEY;
module.exports = KEY;
console.log(KEY);
```

.env

```
KEY="0123456789"
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js (version one - **without** dotenv-webpack plugin)

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' }); 

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/nodeside.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        'process.env.KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.KEY)
      })
    ]
};
```

webpack.config.js (version one - **with** dotenv-webpack plugin)

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/nodeside.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env',
      systemvars: true,
      prefix: true
   })
    ]
};
```

I'm so sorry if some info are unclear or not understandable, I've tried my best to explain but I'm still really new at all of that and really confused of what's going on.

### **TLDR:**

I'm trying to hide my API key on GitHub, while still being able to have a live version of the website on GitHub pages. I'm using dotenv to store my API Key in an .env file and retrieving it in my GitHub Actions workflow with my DOTENV_KEY stored in GitHub secrets. I use webpack (or webpack-dotenv) to bundle the js file where I assign my API key (`process.env.KEY`) to a variable that I export. When I try to import it in another js file and log the value, I get this error in the browser console:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: KEY".

I found some similar posts here but none of the suggested answers seem to work for me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue, but can't seem to resolve even with updated libraries. Have you ever had success with this?

```
"dotenv-vault": "^1.26.1",
"dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
"webpack": "^5.90.3",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35805719)